# Neo4j list nodes with the most nodes in common

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Not quite sure that this is within the scope of Neo4j, so please let me know if I'm just trying to do too much.

Image a graph with 2 types of nodes(`User` and `Item`), and 1 type of relationship (`LIKES`).  I'm trying to list the User nodes in order of the number of similarly liked items by other users.  For example User1 likes 10 Items, and those 10 items are all liked by other users; However all other users only like that one item so the list would look like

```
User1, 10
User2, 1
User3, 3
...
```

My imagination is creating a query that looks like

```
MATCH (u:User)-[e:LIKES]->(i:Item)<-e:LIKES]-(u2:User)
WITH u, count(u-->i<--u2) as num_common
RETURN u, num_common
```

Clearly the `count(u-->i<--u2)` doesn't work, but I'm at a loss as to what it should say.

Is this possible in a Neo4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.  I simplified my query to

```
MATCH (u:User)-[e:LIKES]->(i:Item)<-[e2:LIKES]-(u2:User)
RETURN u, count(i)
ORDER BY count(i) DESC
```